# Keep a 2nd level branch up to date with the first

Tags: git

Sometimes I'll work on a feature in multiple parts because it's a large feature, but each part is dependent on the parts before it.

I'll branch the 2nd part from the 1st part while the 1st part is still being reviewed/tested/etc.. I end up with something like -

```
         ---F2->   (Feature branch part 2)
        /
    ---F1------>   (Feature branch part 1)
   /
--M0---M1---M2->   (master)
```

Everything works great until I'm halfway through Feature part 2 and realize I need to make a change or correct something in Feature part 1.

So I switch back to the 1st feature branch and made the change (and squash it so it remains 1 commit)

```
           ---F2->   (Feature branch part 2)
          /
      ---F1   
     /
    /----F1' (Feature branch part 1)
   /
--M0---M1---M2->   (master)
```

When I go to rebase the Feature part 2 branch to pull in `F1'`, I resolve any conflicts, but it still keeps `F1`. So I end up with a "double commit" of both `F1` and `F1'`.

Is there any way to basically **replace** `F1` with `F1'` when rebasing?

More generally - what's the accepted best practice on how to work with features like this that involve multiple layers of branches? I usually never go past 2, but if there was a good workflow to manage that, I'd have use for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the interactive rebase from B2.

```
$ git checkout B2
$ git rebase -i B1
```

Then simply delete the line of F1 and only keep the line for F1´ and you got what you wanted, switching the commits for one another :)

I used Fi for commit(s) and B for branches. Obviously the rebase is per commit in the editor it opens and I didn't quite catch if we're talking about one or multiple commits in the feature branches.

Answer (score 1):

another option:

```
git checkout F2
git rebase --onto F1 "$(git merge-base --fork-point F1)"
```

Comment: There's even a `--fork-point` option on rebase, `git rebase --fork-point F1 F2` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Git makes this really easy, just tell it what you're tracking.  To make your graph you did e.g. this,

```
git checkout -tb F2         # F2 tracks current checkout (or you could say F1 explicitly)
work work commit commit
git checkout F1             # F1 needs work
work some more
git rebase                  # F1 needs its own rebase
git checkout F2             # back to F2
yet more work
```

which looks pretty deep in the weeds, but this is a really common sequence.  The rebase command from here is

```
git rebase
```

Rebase defaults to `--fork-point` when you rebase on to your default tracking branch, the full spell when you don't (necessarily) have F2 checked out and F2 doesn't track F1 is `git rebase --fork-point F1 F2`.